# DBeaver not showing any Comments/Remarks in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

Recently, I am immigrating some data from Postgresql to a MSSQL2012 server. In SQLWorkbench, I can see comments on tables and columns in SQLServer.

But in `DBeaver`, I can't see any comment or remarks on any object. The Description column in Properties tab are always empty.
Is this a configuration issue, or is DBeaver just not ready for this ?

Both SQLWorkbench and DBeaver are using MS' JDBC driver.

Comment: I am not alone. looks like a known limitation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881213/ms-sql-server-jdbc-driver-does-not-read-remarks

Comment: Sadly, sounds like I have to stick with SqlWorkbench. My major complain with SqlWorkbench is that it corrupt the workspace files after crash, and all my unsaved scripts, connection parameters are gone. Really frustrating...

Comment: did you enable the workspace backup? (Tools -> Options -> Backups) and possibly the "Auto save workspace" option?

Comment: Yes, I did. After the crash, I launched SqlWorkbench as usual and realized things are gone. So I closed it, and tried to find the backup, no avail. Then I briefly opened it to check the backup location. It turned out that the limited number of workspace backups are all overwritten to only a few kb in size just minutes ago... If the backups are automatically moved to a separate folder after each crash, It shouldn't render so lame...

Comment: Did you [report](http://sql-workbench.net/support.html) those problems?

Comment: Not yet, if there is a forum, bug tracker or alike, I probably have already did it. Currently I just increased the backup number to 20. try to remember not to launch and close again after such incident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft JDBC driver does not return that information through the standard JDBC API. I *think* the main reason for that is, that the driver uses `sp_columns` internally (at least the last time I checked - which is a couple of years back) and that procedure doesn't return that information.

I guess DBeaver simply has no special code to retrieve the "extended properties" for tables or columns for SQL Server, whereas SQL Workbench/J ["knows" those extended properties](http://sql-workbench.net/manual/settings.html#dbexplorer-ms-remarks)

Comment: Thanks, looks like among these java-based DB-neural management tools like DBeaver/SQuirrL, only SQL Workbench/J supports this extended properties in MS SQL. I find it very importable to be able to read the comments when working with external teams.